# What are some datasets to train an MLP on simple tasks?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, datasets, multilayer-perceptrons

I have implemented an MLP. Now, I want to train it to solve simple tasks.

Are there any data sets to train the MLP on simple tasks, that is, tasks with a small number of inputs and outputs?

I would like to train it to solve problems which are slightly more complex than the XOR problem.

Comment: Questions that ask for datasets are generally off-topic here. The most appropriate site to ask this type of question is probably Open Data SE.

Answer (score 4):

There are a ton of sample datasets our there you can play with. A bunch of good ones install with R in the datasets package.  Luckily you can download them independently if you're not an R user.  Try  https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/datasets.html

You might also be interested in the [MNIST database](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/) which is one of the canonical databases used in handwriting recognition research.

Beyond that, you can look at / ask on http://datasets.reddit.com and/or http://opendata.reddit.com and you'll find all sorts of useful datasets.

And finally, don't overlook the [UCI Machine Learning Repository](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/).

Answer (score 2):

A popular dataset is the fisher iris dataset. It consists of 150 samples each with a dimensionality of 4. You can find it at
http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Iris

Answer (score 1):

If you want to solve a [multi-class classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification) problem, you could use the famous [iris flower dataset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_flower_data_set), which was [introduced by Fisher in 1936](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/iris). In this dataset, each flower has (only) $4$ features (the inputs), namely

- petal length,
- petal width,
- sepal length, and
- sepal width

There are $3$ classes (the outputs)

- iris setosa,
- iris virginica, and
- iris versicolor

And there are a total of $150$ observations (or records).

The iris flower dataset is available in `sklearn`. See, for example, [Iris plants dataset](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/index.html#iris-plants-dataset).

*To search for other datasets, you can also use https://toolbox.google.com/datasetsearch.*

Answer (score 0):

After almost three years the question is still relevant.

Let me add some too:

[Deep Learning Datasets](http://deeplearning.net/datasets/)

The datasets from the above link can be used for benchmarking deep learning algorithms.

[STL-10 dataset](https://cs.stanford.edu/~acoates/stl10/)

An image dataset which is inspired by [CIFAR-10 dataset](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html)